# DKIM signature for email with alternateview

Tags: .net, dkim

Using asp.net;
I have to send Html emails with a text alternateview and sign it with DKIM.

I have managed to sign emails when it doesn't include an alternateview.
Does anyone have a solution to do so where the email has an alternateview?

Answer (score 1):

there is no difference, i calculate the hash over the complete body - over all alternate parts and the headers.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Net.Mail` is not provide *dkim* with *AlternateView* and *attachment*.
Use [Mimekit](http://www.mimekit.net/) for Dkim with AlternateView and attachment. Its will be worked surely.

Its also open source and better than `.Net.Mail`.